# How to display specific output for specific username in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have made a simple django app. In my models.py I have defined a table-

```
class events(models.Model):
    id_campaign = models.CharField(default='newevent',max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(default='100',max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(default='100',max_length=100)
```

This is my views.py -

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.shortcuts import render
from website.models import *
from website.models import events


from django.views.generic import ListView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'base.html'


class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

class ContactPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'

class Success(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'success.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Success, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query_results = events.objects.all()
        context.update({'query_results': query_results})
        return context
```

And this is the success.html -

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<header>
    <a href=" {% url 'logout'%}">Logout</a>
</header>

{% block content %}
<h2>you are logged in successfully. this is your personal space.</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id_campaign</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>name</th>
   </tr>
    {% for item in query_results %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.id_campaign }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}

{% else %}

<h2>you are not logged in.</h2>

{%endif %}
```

I need to check the username in *success.html* and based on the user I need to show results, how do I do that?

```
if request.user.is_authenticated(): 
  username = request.user.username
```

if username is 'xyz' then I want to display the values from *query_results* and if username is 'abc' then I don't want to display.

P.S. - I am absolutely new to django

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin template tag `if` and do it as below

```
{% if username == 'xyz' %}
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Refer this link for [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-if).